# Como conseguir que en una fila sus items tengan diferentes alturas

Tags: css-grid-layout

¿Se puede conseguir este resultado utilizando el Layout Grid?

Quiero que en una fila sus items tengan diferentes alturas.

```css
.contenedor {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgb(192,192,192);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 75px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
    
  background-color:rgb(255, 140, 0);   
  color: white;
  font-weigh: 900;
  
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;  
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 100px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 150px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  height: 160px;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  height: 175px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si quieres hacer eso con *grid layout* tendrás que meter elementos en las "celdas" ya que lo que haces es una rejilla, funciona de forma similar a una tabla.

Comment: Bueno, lo arregle con jquery y modificando fila a fila. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solo con grid creo que no se puede, tienes que usar js para eso

te dejo una guia completa donde hablan del tema

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb)

hay puedes ver codigo de ejemplos

saludos